# how to use the memcache add-on in heroku cedar?

Tags: heroku, memcached, add-on

I am in the process of (finally) migrating a small heroku app from the bamboo stack to cedar,  following the [migration guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar-migration).

All works well, except I am unable to reinstate the heroku memcache add-on.

Apparently this has been abandoned, or removed, but I cannot find any information about it, is my only option to switch to a different memcache-y add-on? Why did heroku discontinue this add-on?

Comment: It can be a change in the business direction by the addon provider itself that causes an addon to be deprecated (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/memcache)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the day after I submitted this question, heroku notified me and a bunch of other people:

```
Action Required: MEMCACHE ADD-ON IS SHUTTING DOWN
```

In the mail, they themselves suggest switching to memcachier, so that's about it.